# How to list all columns in views with relations - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, view

I made a lot of views with 7-20 columns in each of them. I need to make a query which will return me the list of tables and columns on which is related every column in every view.

Example of my view:

```
CREATE VIEW example AS
SELECT t.NAME, t.AGE, t.ADDRESS, p.MOBILE, p.LAPTOP ...
FROM person t, device p
WHERE ...
```

Query result (needed):

```
TABLE      COLUMN
person     NAME
person     AGE
person     ADDRESS
device     MOBILE
device     LAPTOP
```

Is this possible, and how? It saves me a lot of time (there is over 900 columns in all views).

Thanks

Comment: You can have View names and their column names, but I think SQL Server doesnt store any data from which you can get table names via column names of views, as in views column names might be different then what they were in the tables, do you want a query to get only view names and their respective column names ?

Comment: @M.Ali No, I need query to tell me on wich table and column in my DB is related every column of that view. Just to make list of these relations (as I can get table, column_name... for primary keys, e.g.).

Comment: SQL Server assigns a new object id to column names in views, which is specific to that view, it will have no relation to any other object ids of tables, which is quite understandable as column names in views may or may not be the same as column names in the tables.

Answer (score 0):

Yet you can have this query to pull all the views present in your database along with columns present in them views.

```
SELECT v.name  AS View_Name
      ,c.name  AS Column_Name
FROM sys.views  v 
INNER JOIN sys.all_columns  c  ON v.object_id = c.object_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more elaborated solution, the idea is to convert views to temp tables with no records (select top 0 * from ...) and for each table retrieve the column names from INFORMATION SCHEMA:

```
---Create this table First
CREATE TABLE dbo.Views_Columns(
id INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
ViewName varchar(100),
ColumnName varchar(100)
)

--START
DECLARE @CurrentView varchar(100)
DECLARE @CurrentSchema varchar(50)
--Temp table #AllViews stores all views names
SELECT s.name as SchemaName, v.name as ViewName, 0 as Processed 
INTO #AllViews 
FROM sys.views v INNER JOIN SYS.schemas s ON v.schema_id = s.schema_id

WHILE EXISTS (select * from #AllViews WHERE Processed = 0)
BEGIN

    --Clean up our temp table
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'temp')
    BEGIN
        DROP TABLE dbo.temp
    END

     SELECT TOP 1 @CurrentView = ViewName, @CurrentSchema = SchemaName 
     FROM #AllViews WHERE Processed = 0 

     EXEC('SELECT TOP 0 * INTO dbo.temp FROM '+@CurrentSchema+'.'+@CurrentView)

     INSERT INTO Views_Columns
     SELECT @CurrentSchema+'.'+@CurrentView, Column_name FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'temp' 

     UPDATE #AllViews SET Processed = 1 where ViewName = @CurrentView
END

SELECT * FROM Views_Columns
--END
```